# Can I calculate global variable in HLSL before vertex shader applied?

Tags: hlsl, directx-9

there are three global variable g_A, g_B, g_C
I want to do this; `g_C = g_A * g_B`

I tried this;

```
technique RenderScene
{
    g_C = g_A * g_B;

    pass P0
    {          
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 RenderSceneVS();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_2_0 RenderScenePS(); 
    }
}
```

However, it's improper syntax.
What should I do?

Must I calculate this variable in c++ code before rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX 9 and 10 Effects support "preshaders", where static expressions will be pulled out to be executed on the CPU automatically.

See `D3DXSHADER_NO_PRESHADER` in the documentation, which is a flag that suppresses this behavior. Here's a web link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205441(v=vs.85).aspx

Your declaration of `g_C` is missing both `static` and the type e.g. `float`. You'll also need to move it into global scope.

When you compile it with fxc, you might see something like the following (note the `preshader` block after the comment block):

```
technique RenderScene
{
    pass P0
    {
        vertexshader = 
            asm {
            //
            // Generated by Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
            //
            // Parameters:
            //
            //   float4 g_A;
            //   float4 g_B;
            //
            //
            // Registers:
            //
            //   Name         Reg   Size
            //   ------------ ----- ----
            //   g_A          c0       1
            //   g_B          c1       1
            //

                preshader
                mul c0, c0, c1

            // approximately 1 instruction used
            //
            // Generated by Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
                vs_2_0
                mov oPos, c0

            // approximately 1 instruction slot used
            };

        pixelshader = 
            asm {
            //
            // Generated by Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
                ps_2_0
                def c0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                mov r0, c0.x
                mov oC0, r0

            // approximately 2 instruction slots used
            };
    }
}
```

I compiled the following:

```
float4 g_A;
float4 g_B;
static float4 g_C = g_A * g_B;

float4 RenderSceneVS() : POSITION
{
    return g_C;
}

float4 RenderScenePS() : COLOR
{
    return 0.0;
}

technique RenderScene
{
    pass P0
    {          
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 RenderSceneVS();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_2_0 RenderScenePS();
    }
}
```

with `fxc /Tfx_2_0 t.fx` to generate the listing. They're not very interesting shaders...